# How to disable bootstrap tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have this nav tab

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="pointerTabs">
    <li class="active aa"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#aa">01 Personal</a></li>
    <li class="bb" ><a data-toggle="tab" href="#bb">02 Education</a></li>
    <li class="cc"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cc" >03 Experience</a></li>
    <li class="dd"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#dd">04 Family</a></li>
</ul>
```

on page load am trying to disable all tabs except first tab.So tried adding property

```
$('.bb,.cc,.dd').prop('disabled','true');
```

But Its not working.

How to disable it?any help?How can I use `data-toggle`to enable and disable tabs here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use pointer-events:none on all but the first li

```
.nav.nav-tabs li:not(:first-of-type) a {
  pointer-events:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add this css in you li tag

class="disabledTab"

```
    .disabledTab{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

in you html

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="pointerTabs">
    <li class="active aa disabledTab"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#aa">01 Personal</a></li>
    <li class="bb disabledTab" ><a data-toggle="tab" href="#bb">02 Education</a></li>
    <li class="cc disabledTab"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#cc" >03 Experience</a></li>
    <li class="dd disabledTab"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#dd">04 Family</a></li>
</ul>
```

add disabledtab css in your tab which you want to disabled.

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery and remove the `data-toggle` and `href` attribute, and each time manipulate them on certain events.

Also, if all except one are to be disabled on page load, add a common class to all those that are to be disabled and then use the CSS property `pointer-events`
For eg :

```
.disable
{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```